# webcam using scriptcam getting stucked on opening

Tags: jquery, flash, twitter-bootstrap, webcam, scriptcam

Actually we are using scriptcam plugin for webcam integration in our application. The plugin can be found [here](https://www.scriptcam.com/)

Now the webcam is working but one isssue is there in chrome, As soon as video start showing it gets stucked there only.

We are using it like these

```
$("#webcam").scriptcam({ 
        width: 640,
        height: 480
    });
```

We are showing the video in bootstrap modal window.Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new bug was introduced in Chrome 35 where only the first frame is rendered. See https://www.scriptcam.com/blog.cfm & https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3778961 for more information.

I found disabling hardware acceleration to be unreasonably slow and opted to capture the hidden frozen camera using a JS timeout and render it to a canc